# How to edit/add a using REG command in a MULTI_SZ value type?

Tags: batch-file

Here is my Regedit script:

```
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\Warcraft III]
    "Battle.net Gateways"=hex(7):31,30,30,31,00,30,34,00,75,73,77,65,73,74,2e,62,\
    61,74,74,6c,65,2e,6e,65,74,00,38,00,4c,6f,72,64,\
    61,65,72,6f,6e,28,55,2e,53,2e,20,57,65,73,74,29,\
    00,75,73,65,61,73,74,2e,62,61,74,74,6c,65,2e,6e,\
    65,74,00,36,00,41,7a,65,72,6f,74,68,28,55,2e,53,\
    2e,20,45,61,73,74,29,00,61,73,69,61,2e,62,61,74,\
    74,6c,65,2e,6e,65,74,00,2d,39,00,4b,61,6c,69,6d,\
    64,6f,72,28,41,73,69,61,29,00,65,75,72,6f,70,65,\
    2e,62,61,74,74,6c,65,2e,6e,65,74,00,2d,31,00,4e,\
    6f,72,74,68,72,65,6e,64,28,45,75,72,6f,70,65,29,\
    00,77,33,6c,2e,67,67,75,2e,6c,61,00,2d,39,00,53,\
    6f,75,74,4b,6f,72,65,61,5b,41,73,69,61,5d,00,00
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Blizzard Entertainment\Warcraft III" /v  "Battle.net Gateways" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "1001\004\0uswest.battle.net\08\0Lordaeron(U.S. West)\0useast.battle.net\06\0Azeroth(U.S. East)\0asia.battle.net\0-9\0Kalimdor(Asia)\0europe.battle.net\0-1\0Northrend(Europe)\0w3l.ggu.la\0-9\0SoutKorea[Asia]"
```

By default, a `REG_MULTI_SZ` value in the command line uses `\0` as a delimiter between the strings.